# Change View with its ViewModel based on a ViewModel Property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

As far as I know in WPF you can do something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:IronStage1ViewModel}">
        <Views:IronStage1View/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:IronStage2ViewModel}">
        <Views:IronStage2View/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Views:TestStageToTabIndexConverter x:Key="TestStageToTabIndexConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

**My question:** 
Is there any way to choose the View based on a property in your ViewModel?

something like this:

```
<Window.Resources> //If property Selector==1
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:IronStage1ViewModel}"> 
        <Views:IronStage1View/>
    </DataTemplate>

                   // If property Selector==2
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:IronStage1ViewModel}">
        <Views:IronStage2View/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Data triggers come to mind, this can also be done through converters. Do you have a specific implementation that you are curious about?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you mean exactly bye specific implementation. But just to say I am using Ninject as my DI container and I try to obey all the design patterns as much as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would a datatemplate selector do this?

[tutorial here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)

This is how this would apply to your scenario:

**First create a DataTemplateSelector:**

```
public class IronStageTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate IronStage1Template { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate IronStage2Template { get; set; }

    public object IronStage1Selector { get; set; }
    public object IronStage2Selector { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object selector,
      DependencyObject container)
    {
        if(selector == this.IronStage1Selector)
        {
            return IronStage1Template;
        }

        return IronStage2Template;
    }
}
```

I have extended the tutorial to include properties you can assign for when to return each template.

**Declare the XAML resources**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="iron1Template">
        <TextBlock/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="iron2Template">
        <Label />
    </DataTemplate>

    <System:Double x:Key="Selector1">1</System:Double>
    <System:Double x:Key="Selector2">2</System:Double>

    <local:IronStageTemplateSelector x:Key="IronStageTemplateSelector" 
                                     IronStage1Selector="{StaticResource Selector1}"
                                     IronStage2Selector="{StaticResource Selector2}"
                                     IronStage1Template="{StaticResource iron1Template}"
                                     IronStage2Template="{StaticResource iron2Template}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In this example we have declared our selector so that when our property has value 1, template1 is returned, otherwise we get template 2.

**Add Control to XAML**
Finally, a little hack is needed - your VM property needs to be IEnumerable...

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding toProperty}" 
     ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource IronStageTemplateSelector}">
</ItemsControl>
```

I hope this helps, please mark as answer if you found it useful

Comment: This should be the answer but you'll want to give a little details in case the url ever becomes invalid.

Comment: Sure - posted answer from phone so will update from desktop tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks @kidshaw. it works. Just for they who might want to see Video tutorial of the DataTemplateSelector, check this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAbshQcI1BA) out as well

Comment: Half the answer is first knowing what to google! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the view model property of known type at compile time? if so you can just add the control directly into main (parent) view and bind datacontext to the view model property.

something like this..

```
   <Address:AddressControl Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" DataContext="       {Binding PresentAddress}"/>
```

Just let me know if you have different scenario.