# In WPF MVVM on button click how to have my view do something before or after the Command reference to the view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

On one form I have a Label and an Edit Button.  When the Edit Button is clicked the control template for the label changes to show a TextBox and a Save Button.  That Save Button is tied to a Save Command on the View Model.

My question / problem is, when the Save button is clicked I want it to change the control template back to being a label either before or after the Command Executes on the View Model.  In my particular case all it needs to do is set a property on my label to True whenever the Save Button is Clicked in addition to the command being executed.

```
conv:ReadOnlyControlTemplate.DoLock="True"
```

**UPDATE**
I am much closer now thanks to some of the feedback in answers below.  I am using the following for the Save Button:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <ei:DataTrigger Comparison="Equal" Binding="{Binding Test, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="CommandUpdated"  >
                                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction  PropertyName="conv:ReadOnlyControlTemplate.DoLock" Value="True" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ShiftManagerMessages}" /> 
                                        </ei:DataTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Changing to TargetObject from TargetName of the ei:ChangePropertyAction caused it to see the Label correctly.  However now I get the following error:

{"Cannot find a property named \"conv:ReadOnlyControlTemplate.DoLock\" on type \"Label\"."}

I can point it to other properties, just not this one and I don't understand why?

Comment: I couldn't point to that property because it was an attached property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of using DataTrigger to control template:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NextPlc.Instore.Epos.Till.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label" x:Key="ReadOnlyTemplate"></ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label" x:Key="EditTemplate"></ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
        <ei:DataTrigger.Actions>
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="label" PropertyName="Template" Value="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTemplate}"/>
        </ei:DataTrigger.Actions>
    </ei:DataTrigger>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="False">
        <ei:DataTrigger.Actions>
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="label" PropertyName="Template" Value="{StaticResource EditTemplate}"/>
        </ei:DataTrigger.Actions>
    </ei:DataTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="label">
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the problem correct, but you can run some code behind in your view by subscribing to various (preview)mousedown events of your button and change your layout there. That is, if you have nth against using code behind in an MVVM project. Your button will than trigger both the command handler in your VM, and event handler in your view.

```
<Button MouseDown="Button_MouseDown" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />

 private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    // Set your property
 }
```

Comment: I did not find this to be the case at all.  Having a Click defined on the button effectively superseded the command which did not run at all.  Removing the Click attribute caused the Command to run normally.

Comment: You can than optionally execute command from click event: var btn = sender as Button; btn.Command.Execute(btn.CommandParameter);

Comment: The only problem there is that the btn.Command will be null.  For whatever reason you can't see the command that was set in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Code behind is an option, but consider what to do if your command fails. If you've got a ViewModel there, you can use a data trigger or template selector bound to a property.

I posted an answer last week about how to write a data template selector and bind a control to it... [Change View with its ViewModel based on a ViewModel Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916726/change-view-with-its-viewmodel-based-on-a-viewmodel-property/24918915#24918915)

Doing this with a DataTrigger - add a reference to Microsoft.Expressions.Interactions, then add the XAML...

```
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

in your namespace, then...

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewModel.State}" Value="CommandUpdated">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    </ei:DataTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This works by triggering based on a property 'State' in the viewmodel. In this case state is an Enumeration where CommandUpdated is a value of that enum - it could as easily be a bool or int.

Comment: What namespace is i:Interaction.Triggers from?  I tried adding:  xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" But it doesn't like it.

Comment: xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
 xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
Have you added the references to your project?

Comment: Sorry it was confused and throwing me the wrong error, fixed after a clean.  What its actually complaining about is the Setter Tag, it says it expects a TriggerAction.

Comment: It looks like its expecting a TriggerAction where the Setter tag is.  I can use <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="ShiftManagerMessages" PropertyName="conv:ReadOnlyControlTemplate.DoLock" Value="True" /> in its place which will build.  However it doesn't seem to do anything at runtime.  Do I have to do anything extra to reference a custom attribute?

Comment: I also added a TestConverter in the ei:DataTrigger binding to make sure the value was being set and picked up correctly, which it is.  Its just that the ei:ChangePropertyAction fails to do anything.  Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Apologies - I originally had this trigger a storyboard which set the properties, I over simplified it.

Comment: That's alright, it was still extremely close to what I was looking for.  Now I'm just trying to get it to see my property.

Comment: Using the ChangePropertyAction is correct, but you want to target your templated control and set its template to either your label or textbox template