# how to dynamically change rectangle color in Expander?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, controltemplate, expander

I have an Expander in which i have Rectangle with color. i want to change dynamically after some functionality. how to change it on run time ?

```
 <Windows.Resources>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SimpleExpanderButtonTemp" 
         TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Border x:Name="ExpanderButtonBorder"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle x:Name="ExpandRect" Fill="Transparent"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

        <Ellipse Name="Circle"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Stroke="DarkGray"
             Width="20"
             Height="20"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             />

    </Grid>
</Border>
</>
</Windows.Resources>
```

Anyone help :

Comment: What is the runtime event that triggers the change?

Comment: actually in expander i have a grid , and some checkboxes, i want when all checkboxes are checked, the rectangle color should be green. thats why i want to access the rectangle and dynamically change its color.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change this in code behind, I would bind to a brush resource using {DynamicResource key} binding. Your code behind can then update that resource to whatever you want where ever you need it to.

```
this.Resource["RectangleBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

If you want to control it via data in a view model, use a datatrigger. [Link to similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996817/in-wpf-mvvm-on-button-click-how-to-have-my-view-do-something-before-or-after-the/24999299#24999299)

If you're basing it on multiple bindings - you can use a multibinding with a converter : [Tutorial here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/809/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings)

Comment: I did something like this, but it still wont change the color of      rectangle in expander bodrder... 
    System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle temprect = (System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle)FindResource("ExpandRect");

temprect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

Answer (score 0):

```
<Rectangle Fill="Transparent" x:Name="ExpanderButtonRectangle"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

ExpanderButtonRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Comment: i tried it, i cant access rectangle directly in my code, i may will have to search through findresource as i have it in <Window.resources>
but as i have rectangle inside ControlTemplate -> Boder -> grid so i dnt knw how to access it.