# How do you access Expander content dynamically?

Tags: wpf, dynamic, datagrid, wpf-controls, expander

I have multiple dynamic generated Expanders having DataGrid as Content, and CheckBoxes in DataGrid. I got the DataGrid with the following code below but don't know how to get the Expander.

```
    private void ChkBoxDamage_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    CheckBox b = (CheckBox)e.Source;
    DataGridRow row = b.TemplatedParent.TryFindParent<DataGridRow>();
    row.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
    DataGrid dataGrid = b.TemplatedParent.TryFindParent<DataGrid>();
    Expander Gridexpanderr = dataGrid.TemplatedParent.TryFindParent<Expander>();
    Gridexpanderr.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
```

The above code won't change expander Background Color.

Comment: Have you tried `dataGrid.TryFindParent<Expander>()` directly?...

Comment: Why all the codebehind? Why not just bind to the properties and/or use a IValueConverter to set the color directly in the xaml instead?

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you delete all this code and learn to use WPF properly. WPF is about XAML and DataBinding, not procedural code. Whatever items-based (i.e "repeater"-like) UI requires an `ItemsControl` and proper `DataTemplate`s, rather than a bunch of ugly procedural code.

Comment: Ok guys then i asked question for same problem in XAML, if you can help this is the link... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138707/how-to-dynamically-change-rectangle-color-in-expander