# How to load different controls depending on the databound classes type in WPF

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a problem which I have soled on my own but I do not like the solution because of it's complexity and dependency of a lot of events and it is not according to the guidelines of MVVM, so I would like to do it the right way and re-factor it.
Also I have to emphasize that this is a simplified example of the problem

Before everything, I have a Base Class

```
public abstract class CommonBaseClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have several Classes that inherit from the base class

```
public class DateClass : CommonBaseClass
{
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TextClass : CommonBaseClass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class TrueClass : CommonBaseClass
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

I a usercontrol I have an observable collection of the base class objects.

```
ObservableCollection<CommonBaseClass> DataCollection = new ObservableCollection<CommonBaseClass>();
```

The Collection "DataCollection" is bound to a itemscontrol.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}">

    </ItemsControl>
```

I would like to bind to the collection to the itemscontrol in a way that depending on the type of the class inheriting the base one, a different control will be loaded and databound with maximum customization

So If an item from the control is  a type of the TextClass, the object will be bound to a label, if it is a type of TrueClass it will be bound to a ChackBox and if it is a CateClass it will be bound to custom UserControl that Contains a DatePicker, textBox and a Button that executes some code.

I have already a solution that is working but in my opinion it is really bad because it creates the different controls in a converter, and that it waits for the different load  events and binds everything manually. As I said really bad.

I am sure that there has to be a better "MVVM way" of implementing this in XAML.

I am using converters, templates, and resource dictionaries (also merged ones), so I would appreciate real "By the book solutions"

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Have you tried using a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: nope, one miunte ago I found the following example. Right before you pasted it.
http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector. 

The DataTemplateSelektor seems to be the solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is commonly adressed by using DataTemplates eventually in combination with DataTemplateSelectors if there is more complex logic involved on how to choose the correct template based on the binding.
For the scenario described it should be sufficient to define the specific data templates in resources and specify the DataType Property of the DataTemplate. 
WPF then chooses the correct template based on the type of the bound object.

The technical details are described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use data template selector. If you want a stripped down complete example, see my answer to [this stack overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916726/change-view-with-its-viewmodel-based-on-a-viewmodel-property/24918915#24918915)

Answer (score 0):

I once solved a similar problem by specifying all three potential controls in the ItemControl's `ItemTemplate`, and use a converter to set the `Visibility` of two of the controls to `Hidden` and one to `Visible` based on the actual data type. This allows you to set up all the three controls including bindings in XAML, without the need of codebehing or event-code.

One problem might be that in case of the `TextClass` and `TrueClass` types, the DatePicker control would still be present within the DataTemplate (although invisible) and binding to a `Name` property that does not exist on the current type - but without giving it a try I would assume that XAML is tolerant enough to just ignore this inappropriate binding.

Comment: this is simpler than my solution, But honestly I do not like the throwing away of resource like that. In my specific case I have 12 different Child Classes and in a collection in average case, about 100 items. This might be a bit of vasteful.